# pass angular scope to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

anyone has any case like me ? i have to connect another service to my system. the problem is that service is unsupported on JS front-end (im using angularJS). to show form for service i need to complete jQuery form like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var data = new Object();
data.req_merchant_code = '1';
data.req_chain_merchant = 'NA';
data.req_payment_channel = '15'; // ‘15’ = credit card
data.req_transaction_id = '<?php echo $invoice ?>';
data.req_currency = '<?php echo $currency ?>';
data.req_amount = '<?php echo $amount ?>';
data.req_words = '<?php echo $words ?>';
data.req_form_type = 'full';
getForm(data);
});
</script>
```

like you see that PHP variable on there with echo, can anyone help me to pass scope variable to that jQuery. i set that variable like this

```
$scope.dokuPayment = function(){
            topUpFactory.createwordsDoku().then(function(data){
            console.log(data.data);
            var req = data.data;
            $scope.invoice = req.invoice;
            $scope.words = req.words;
            $scope.currency = req.currency;
            $scope.amount = req.amount;
            console.log(invoice);
            $("#doku-modal").modal('show');
            });
        }
```

i try to put that scope to parametes like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      console.log("form doku");

      $(function() {
      var data = new Object();
      data.req_merchant_code = '3279';
      data.req_chain_merchant = 'NA';
      data.req_payment_channel = '15'; // ‘15’ = credit card
      data.req_transaction_id = {{invoice}};
      data.req_currency = {{currency}};
      data.req_amount = {{amount}};
      data.req_words = {{words}};
      data.req_form_type = 'full';
      getForm(data);
      });

      </script>
```

but doesn't work.. i try to set upperstroup ("") still doesn't work. anyone can help. . thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using AngularJS, try avoiding using jQuery in that way.

$("#doku-modal").modal('show'); - not a good idea to do that in this framework.

This article may give some guidance: http://www.dwmkerr.com/the-only-angularjs-modal-service-youll-ever-need/

In $scope.dokuPayment you can potentially do the same thing what getForm(data) does as long as it does not manipulate the DOM directly.

As a result, you do not have to pass any data to the view as the entire JS logic should be in your Angular services or controllers.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple hack, not sure if it is good practice or not! You can make use of **$window** scope. 
All you need to do is, make angular variables to global variables using **$window.{variable name}** and access them from outside using **window.{variable name}**.

See here:

```
$scope.dokuPayment = function(){
            topUpFactory.createwordsDoku().then(function(data){
            console.log(data.data);
            var req = data.data;
            $window.invoice = req.invoice;
            $window.words = req.words;
            $window.currency = req.currency;
            $window.amount = req.amount;
            console.log(invoice);
            $("#doku-modal").modal('show');
            });
        }
```

Outside AngularJS:

```
console.log("form doku");
  $(function() {
  var data = new Object();
  data.req_merchant_code = '3279';
  data.req_chain_merchant = 'NA';
  data.req_payment_channel = '15'; // ‘15’ = credit card
  data.req_transaction_id = window.invoice;
  data.req_currency = window.currency;
  data.req_amount = window.amount;
  data.req_words = window.words;
  data.req_form_type = 'full';
  getForm(data);
  });
```

This worked for me. Hope this helps :)